# Sharepoint framework, environment specific build configs

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

How to separate string constants depends on environment (dev\test\prod) build in Sharepoint Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a dev on the team - Interesting question. We don't have a way to do that with config files or manifests right now, but they can do it by saying something like

`const strings = DEBUG ? require('debug_strings') : require('prod_strings');`

And listing "debug_strings" and "prod_strings" as separate entries in their config.json. This is switching on build flavor, not environment, but that might be similar to what they have in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Question is unclear. Constant is something that is hard coded. You can take the values from web.config entries. So each time you move the code to new environment, you just need to change the values in web.config file which is accessible.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595288/reading-a-key-from-the-web-config-using-configurationmanager

Comment: This is what I want in Sharepoint Framework but there is no web.config. So, the answer is not relative to Sharepoint Framework.

Comment: Web.config file is nothing but a .xml file, is there no possibility to have a separate xml file and read the values using C# Code?

Comment: There is only typescript. No c# code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138690/read-a-local-xml-file-in-angular-typescript-and-extract-some-node-values

Comment: I want to have config information inside solution without querying some files or services.

Comment: How can you change Values inside the solution when you change the environment? XML File or Web.Config gives you the flexibility to change the values without touching the solution when you change the environment.